# Is it possible to use a BindingList<T> with the ListView control in a similar way to the ListBox control?

Tags: c#, listview, controls, listbox, bindinglist

A simple example:

```
BindingList<Dog> dogs = kennel.Dogs;

// Works great!
listBoxDogs.DataSource = dogs;

// Confuses me.
listViewDogs.? = dogs;
```

I have explored the listViewDogs.DataBindings property, but I have not been able to tease out of it similar behavior to what I am seeing with the listBox control using DataSource.

There has to be a better method of updating the listViewDogs.Items collection then catching the dogs.ListChanged event and doing the manipulation of the listViewDogs.Items collection by hand.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list view unfortunately does not support databinding in that way.

here is a tutorial on how to implement it by creating a new control though.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ListView_DataBinding.aspx

ps. there are many more out there!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the example on CodeProject from the accepted answer is terrible.

So,

> there are many more out there!

But where?

Wait, here's one. I've implemented a way simplier, tested and, what's most important, ready to use extension of the `ListView`.

Well, it's not really bindable but it supports any generic class that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` whose underlying type is implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, such as `ObservableCollection<T>` `where T : INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public class BindableListView : ListView
{
    private const string DataCategoryName = "Data";


    private INotifyCollectionChanged _collection;
    [Category(DataCategoryName)]
    public INotifyCollectionChanged Collection
    {
        get { return _collection; }
        set
        {
            if (_collection != null) _collection.CollectionChanged -= CollectionChanged;
            _collection = value;
            BindObject(_collection);
            if (_collection != null) _collection.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private const bool DefaultDefaultBrowsableState = false;
    [Category(DataCategoryName)]
    [DefaultValue(DefaultDefaultBrowsableState)]
    public bool DefaultBrowsableState { get; set; } = DefaultDefaultBrowsableState;


    private void BindObject(object obj)
    {
        Clear();
        if (obj != null)
        {
            Columns.AddRange(obj.GetType().GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault()?.GetProperties().Where(p =>
            {
                return p.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<BrowsableAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()?.Browsable ?? DefaultBrowsableState;
            }).Select(p =>
            {
                return new ColumnHeader()
                {
                    Name = p.Name,
                    Text = p.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<DisplayNameAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()?.DisplayName ?? p.Name
                };
            }).ToArray());
            AddItems(obj as System.Collections.IEnumerable);
            AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
            AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
        }
    }

    private void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                AddItems(e.NewItems);
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                foreach (var oldItem in e.OldItems)
                {
                    if (Items.OfType<ListViewItem>().FirstOrDefault(item => Equals(item.Tag, oldItem)) is ListViewItem itemToRemove)
                    {
                        UnregisterItem(oldItem);
                        Items.Remove(itemToRemove);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                if (e.OldItems.Count == e.NewItems.Count)
                {
                    var count = e.OldItems.Count;
                    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        var itemPair = new { Old = e.OldItems[i], New = e.NewItems[i] };
                        if (Items.OfType<ListViewItem>().FirstOrDefault(item => Equals(item.Tag, itemPair.Old)) is ListViewItem itemToReplace)
                        {
                            UnregisterItem(itemPair.Old);
                            RegisterItem(itemPair.New);
                            itemToReplace.Tag = itemPair.New;
                            foreach (ColumnHeader column in Columns)
                            {
                                itemToReplace.SubItems[column.Index].Text = itemPair.New.GetType().GetProperty(column.Name).GetValue(itemToReplace)?.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                foreach (var oldItem in e.OldItems)
                {
                    if (Items.OfType<ListViewItem>().FirstOrDefault(item => Equals(item.Tag, oldItem)) is ListViewItem itemToMove)
                    {
                        Items.Remove(itemToMove);
                        Items.Insert(e.NewStartingIndex, itemToMove);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                Items.Clear();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
        AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
    }

    private void AddItems(System.Collections.IEnumerable items)
    {
        Items.AddRange((items ?? Enumerable.Empty<object>()).OfType<object>().Select(item =>
        {
            RegisterItem(item);
            return new ListViewItem(Columns.OfType<ColumnHeader>().Select(column =>
            {
                return item.GetType().GetProperty(column.Name).GetValue(item)?.ToString() ?? "";
            }).ToArray())
            {
                Tag = item
            };
        }).ToArray());
    }

    private void RegisterItem(object item)
    {
        if(item is INotifyPropertyChanged observableItem) observableItem.PropertyChanged += ObservableItem_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void UnregisterItem(object item)
    {
        if (item is INotifyPropertyChanged observableItem) observableItem.PropertyChanged -= ObservableItem_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void ObservableItem_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Items.OfType<ListViewItem>().FirstOrDefault(itm => Equals(itm.Tag, sender)) is ListViewItem item)
        {
            if (Columns[e.PropertyName] is ColumnHeader column)
                item.SubItems[column.Index].Text = sender.GetType().GetProperty(e.PropertyName).GetValue(sender)?.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

There are only two things you should know about using this class.

1. The main difference between Out of the box `ListView` is the new property called `Collection` of type `INotifyCollectionChanged`. You can still manipulate the `Items` collection but I wouldn't recommend that. It is expected that the object you are providing as the data source is implementing `IEnumerable` interface and also its underlying type is implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The reason I didn't constrained the `Collection` property to these interfaces was that I wanted to avoid additional casting when assinging the property. You can always add additional checking for these interfaces and throw an ArgumentException just to avoid any unexpected behaviors.
2. There's additional property called `DefaultBrowsableState` which sets the default visibility of the columns representing properties of the data source object that have no `BrowsableAttribute` specified. The reason for this is when you using this `ListView` along with another control which uses the `BrowsableAttribute` (such as `PropertyGrid`) and you want to hide some properties in the list while preserve their visibility on the other control. You can then set the `DefaultBrowsableState` to false and add `[Browsable(true)]` attribute to all properties you want to see in the list.